# Get last node from Firebase database to textview android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get last "current unit" of unique customer from Firebase database.I'm new to here. Please help me. Here is my database snapshot:

[image: Firabase Database]

I tried to with this code. But not value pass to textview. I don't know where is the error.Not Showing any errors.

```
 databaseBills = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("bills");
    Query lastQuery = databaseBills.child("bills").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.child("current_units").getValue(String.class);

            textView17.setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: `java != javascript`!

Comment: The first thing is to stop ignoring errors and implement `onCancelled`: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: I tried. But value not passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code needs to handle that list by iterating over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String value = childSnapshot.child("current_units").getValue(String.class);
    Log.d("onDataChange", "current_units="+value);
    textView17.setText(value);
  }
}
```

---

I highly recommend always adding logging statements like the one above to your code when troubleshooting. If the log shows a value but the UI doesn't, you know the problem is not in reading from the database. If the log doesn't show a value, you know the problem **is** in reading from the database. Either way: you've reduced the problem space, and can ask a more targeted question.

Comment: hi Frank van, can you help me to pass "textView17"  value outside of listener?

Comment: The up to date value will only be available inside the `onDataChange()`.

Comment: How can I pass that value outside of listener? Is there any method?

Comment: You can **pass** the value to another method. But calling that method must happen from with `onDataChange()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting something because you are using a wrong query. You need to remove `.child("bills")` call because under `bills` node there isn't another `bills` child. So your query should look like this:

```
Query lastQuery = databaseBills.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

Comment: Yeah thanx. I understood that. I tried also with this code,but not pass value to textview.

Comment: Why do you say that? Have you also tried to iterate over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` as Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his answer?